# Can a torrent client run with 4KB of RAM?

Tags: microcontroller, bittorrent

On a microchip.
Is it possible to run a torrent client with only 4KB of RAM?

I'm talking about a really optimized version.

Comment: Possible, maybe... Useful & practical? Not so sure... You'd need to manage an Ethernet port including a TCP/IP stack and some storage at the very least, and have enough RAM left to handle the torrents.

Comment: If this were possible, (and I haven't looked at the bit torrent spec), what would you do with the tiny buffers of downloaded data from the one torrent peer?

Comment: I got a few ideas; I can handle Ethernet, and use a SD card for storage. And, I could store downloaded data directly to the card, instead of storing it in the RAM.

Comment: Also, it would be practical. Especially with Wireless (can handle this, too), it can be portable. And can be run on batteries.

Comment: @Bogdacutu - so you need to run a file system as well, in this 4K of RAM?

Comment: Main problem with such amount of RAM I think will be not implementing protocol itself, but providing normal transfer rate. What MCU you want to use? Also, bittorent client needs rather time-consuming operation from time to time - calculating hashes. So you should consider this too before choosing any MCU.

Comment: @Bogdacutu - I'm sorry if I sound pessimistic, it's just that I'm pessimistic - that 4K is beginning to sound a bit small, now.  The only SD drivers/file systems I have experience of need at least one 512 byte buffer and a reasonable stack size.

Comment: OK, 8K of RAM total.  Getting a more reasonable bet..

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting to this? Yes or not? The only real answer is **it depends**, which isn't really the type of question we're searching for on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray - good comment - we agree on something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your implementation and how much Flash is available, yes 4K should be more than enough to run a single connection TCP-IP stack while running BitTorrent without P2P encryption.